# groupby aggregation return different column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

suppose i have  a df and i want to groupby 'item' and aggregate on min and max of thing1 but return thing2. so for item 'c' the min is 1 so 0 is returned  and the max is 3 so 100 is returned

| item | thing1 | thing2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10 |
| a | 4 | 20 |
| b | 1 | 30 |
| c | 1 | 0 |
| c | 2 | 10 |
| c | 3 | 100 |

| item | min_thing1 -> thing2 | max_thing1 -> thing2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 20 |
| b | 30 | 30 |
| c | 0 | 100 |

I know i can aggregate min and max on thing1 by simply writing :

`df.groupby('item').agg({'thing1' : [np.min, np.max]})`

but how would i aggragate on thing2 by using min and max on thing1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `min`/`max` directly

```
>>> df.groupby('item').agg(lambda s: [s.min()['thing2'], s.max()['thing2']])
```

---

```
      thing1  thing2
item                
a         10      20
b         30      30
c          0     100
```

Can, of course, rename the columns after the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df.groupby('item')['thing1'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax']).stack().map(df['thing2']).unstack()
```

Output:

```
      idxmin  idxmax
item                
a         10      20
b         30      30
c          0     100
```